# wsfull just loading database

Tags: out-of-memory, kdb

I'm not sure what to do.  I have a simple 4-column database (with many rows) and all I'm doing is `` load `mydatabase `` but I'm getting `'wsfull`.  I tried to start q with `` q --m `e:/ `` but that doesn't help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How have you saved your database? If you have saved your table as a single file, when you load it in with \l, it copies the table into memory, which is causing the wsfull error.

I would recommend looking at Q for Mortals, it explains how to splay and partition your tables, so when you load the database the table files are not actually copied into memory. The sym file will be though if present, if you have symbols which will need to be enumerated when splaying.

The links below are worth reading through to understand how to best structure a KDB database to avoid memory constraints. KDB is designed to only load in the files required during queries. Selecting column files without constraints will memory map the data, allowing you to access it quickly without copying the data into memory.

https://code.kx.com/q4m3/14_Introduction_to_Kdb%2B/#142-splayed-tables

https://code.kx.com/q4m3/14_Introduction_to_Kdb%2B/#143-partitioned-tables

Comment: Thank you very much and sorry for the late reply. I was trying out some things before I wasted any more of your time.  I was trying to make things as simple as possible by not splaying but your advice was correct. Splaying the table solved the problem. (BTW, I was using 64bit).

Thanks again.

Comment: No problem, glad it worked for you. Would you be able to accept the answer? (it makes it easier for other users with the same problem to see which solution solved the issue)

Comment: Sorry.  There you go.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

As well as Adams answer it's also worth asking what version of kdb you're using, how much memory limit you have etc. Older, non-licenced (32bit) versions of kdb might have 4gb memory limits for example. Can you show us the output of:

1. Your kdb banner, e.g.

```
KDB+ 3.5t 2017.02.28 Copyright (C) 1993-2017 Kx Systems
m32/ 4()core 8192MB sjt mint.local 192.168.0.39 NONEXPIRE
```

2. The output of:

```
.z.o
.z.l
.z.K
.z.k
.Q.w[]
```

whose content are documented here: https://code.kx.com/q/ref/#z

Comment: Thank you. It took me some time to work out but splaying the table solved the problem as Adam suggested.